# QString .arg function

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I am currently playing around with QStrings in QT and can't seem to understand why the following code is not working for me.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString test;

    int x = 5;

    test.append("This is a test of the Arg Function %1").arg(x);
    qDebug() << test;
    //should output This is a test of the Arg Function 5
    return a.exec();
}
```

The output I am getting is:

> This is a test of the Arg Function %1

Obviously I am expecting the value 5 to replace the %1, am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: I think it should be: `test.append(QString("This is a test of the Arg Function %1").arg(x));`

Comment: Didn't compiler warn you about `test.append("This is a test of the Arg Function %1").arg(x);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `test =  test.append("This is a test of the Arg Function %1").arg(x);` because `arg` returns new string.

Example from [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#arg):

```
QString i;           // current file's number
QString total;       // number of files to process
QString fileName;    // current file's name

QString status = QString("Processing file %1 of %2: %3")
                .arg(i).arg(total).arg(fileName);
```

Or like [vahancho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2674506/vahancho) suggested:

```
test.append(QString("This is a test of the Arg Function %1").arg(x));
```

[Michael Burr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12711/michael-burr) suggested:

```
test += QString("This is a test of the Arg Function %1").arg(x);
```

Another one without `arg`:

```
test.sprintf("This is a test of the Arg Function %d", x);
```

And you may have a look at that guy [How to format a QString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784155/how-to-format-a-qstring)

Comment: Or `test += QString("This is a test of the Arg Function %1").arg(x);`

Answer (score 0):

Because you don`t read documentation on QString::arg. It returns copy of the string.

```
qDebug() << test.arg(x) - it`s must work
```